# Infopath form view

Tags: document-library, infopath, infopath-view

I currently open infopath files save in a SharePoint library through a webpart.

The user can enter the the file name in a textbox and click a button and the file will open.

The URL is like:

```
http://servername/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/InstrumentsLib/" + fileName + "&Source=http://b1544:8080/InstrumentsLib/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1";`m
```

Right now the web part works fine, but I want the infopath file to open in a specific view, the infopath template has 2 views.

I want the file to open in the 2nd view.

How can I do this?

The form is web based.

Comment: You already asked this. I am redirecting your old question to this one, but in future please could you edit your original question rather than asking a new one. Thanks.[mod]

Answer (score -1):

Found a way.

```
http://servername/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/InstrumentsLib/" + fileName + "&Source=http://b1544:8080/InstrumentsLib/Forms/AllItems.aspx**&DefaultView=viewname**&DefaultItemOpen=1";
```